# Why does a char array need one element more than expected?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I have noticed that often when I set a character array the exact size it would need, the data stored in that array gets corrupted. Why does that happen, and how much space more should I allocate an array than the maximum size I would need to store data at?

Comment: "I have noticed that often when I set a character array the exact size it would need, the data stored in that array gets corrupted" - that shouldn't happen - unless you're missing the space for the null-terminator, in which case your array isn't getting corrupted but your array is **not** the exact size it needs to be (it's 1 element too small!).

Comment: Strings in C are null-terminated. `strlen` returns number of characters. `+1` acounts for the final zero byte. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling

Comment: @Dai Your comment does not make a sense because without knowing the context  in which the corruption occurs you can say nothing. And the author of the question did not provide any relevant code. The question should be closed.

Comment: occupying more memory than needed is not a good idea , this will make program slow.

Comment: "Why does that happen" --> because your understanding of the "exact size it would need" is incorrect.  By showing the code and the reasoning you think it is the exact size, this could be a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is it recommended to give an array more size than needed?

That is not true for all array types. It is not recommended and also your array´s content should not get touched in any manner if you don´t set more elements than required. However, there is one special exception - storing strings in an array of `char`s, as explained as following.

> I have noticed that often when I set a character array the exact size it would need, the data stored in that array gets corrupted.

When you want to store a string in a `char` array, you have to consider the terminating null character - `\0`.

This character is implied for the reason, that a string-operating function can determine the end of a string and also detects whether a `char` array´s content is part of a string or not.

If you don´t mind to set place for that character and attempt to store a string in that char array, the program will cause a buffer overflow in memory - the `\0` will get written beyond the bounds of the array as it only have space for the proper string content, but not the null character.

> How much space more should I allocate an array than the maximum size I would need to store data at?

Just 1 `char` element more is needed to hold the `\0`.

F.e.:

```
char a[6] = "hello";
```

`a` needs to be consisted of 6, not 5 elements, because it needs to hold the terminating null character.

In comparison,

```
int b[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

`b` doesn´t need to have more elements than explicitly required.

---

So as conclusion, when you want to store a string in a `char` array, imply one element more than needed to store the proper characters of the string alone.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on that type of data that you want to store in an array and can have a number of complicated answers.

Generally, I would say for data you can allocate exactly what you need and not a byte more.   **For strings ensure you allocate a single additional byte for the null terminator.**

There are plenty of resources to read more about the operations of arrays:

https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/C_arrays.html

https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/C_Programming/Arrays.html

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm