# How to create your own strcpy function?

Tags: c

I tried creating my own strcpy function but it could not work when i want to test it in my main function. It tells me that there is a segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *ft_strcpy(char *dest, char *src)
{
    int char_counter = 0;
    
    while (src[char_counter] != '\0')
    {
        dest[char_counter] = src[char_counter];
        char_counter++;
    }
    dest[char_counter] = '\0';
    return (dest);
}

int main()
{
    char *x;
    char *y;
    char f[5];
    char u[5] = "Hello";

    x = f;
    y = u;
    ft_strcpy(x, y);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", x[i]);
    }
    
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: `u` is too small.

Comment: As is `f`. Add one for the null byte. The compiler should have warned you about u. Don't hard code a size and let the compiler figure it out. `char u[] = "Hello"`

Comment: Violation of the basic rule *Never skimp on buffer size!* Also since `src` isn't changed, you can make the parameter `const char *src`.

Comment: `char *cp = dest ; do *dest++ = *src; while (*src++); return cp;`

Comment: Side note: instead of `x = f; y = u; ft_strcpy(x, y);` you can write directly `ft_strcpy(f, u);` and drop `x` and `y` alltogether. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 3):

**Problem:**

As you've defined size of the character array `u` as `5`, if you type more than five characters then the extra characters and the null terminator will be written outside the end of the array, overwriting memory not belonging to the array. This is a buffer overflow.

As a result you'll get [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

**Solution:**

To get the correct output from your code, define `u` as below

```
char u[6] = "Hello";    // need space to keep  null terminator at the end of the character array
```

Or

```
char u[] = "Hello";
```

**Note:** the target array `f` must also be at least as big as `u`

Please check the following resources to learn about it more:

- [Arrays and Strings - Code Monk](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/array-and-strings-code-monk/)
- [Why does a char array need one element more than expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61016257/why-does-a-char-array-need-one-element-more-than-expected)
- [Null-Terminated Character Arrays](https://classes.mst.edu/compsci1570/ntca.htm)

Comment: Unfortunately, C allows declaring a `char` array with a size that can't fit the null terminator. C++, for example, does not, and would throw an error on that declaration. If the declaration had size 4, the C compiler would throw an error as well, as it cannot fit the entire string inside the array, but unfortunately, if it can fit all the characters in the string, excluding the null terminator, it will not throw an error and instead create the array.

Comment: Nice and well documented answer.

Comment: @Dúthomhas thanks for mentioning. Added as a note.